# Removing row from data table using checkbox Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using checkbox to remove a row from data table; when I check one of the boxes; the row is removed. But if i check all the boxes; it gives this error message ***There is no row at position 1.***. And if I go back to checking one box no row is removed.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = row.FindControl("chkInvoice") as CheckBox;
            if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
            {

                dt.Rows.RemoveAt(row.RowIndex);


            }

        }


        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use foreach, you will be modifying the rows while iterating them. So do a reverse loop and remove based on index.

```
for(int i = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var row = GridView1.Rows[i];
    CheckBox chk = row.FindControl("chkInvoice") as CheckBox;
    if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
    {
       dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error There is no row at position 4. Not sure if it is because it checking the header

Comment: if have a column that rows the row number; on deleting how could I reset the row number; for example I have three rows 1 2 3 and I select to delete row 2 then it should be row 1 2 and row 1 3; how could I solve this